# How can I <staircase> the alphabet in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, alphabetical

how could I do something like this:

```
A - B -C - etc - Z
AA - AB - AC -AZ
BA - BB -BC - etc -BZ
CA - CB - CC - ETC -CZ
THEN the same until Z
ZA - ZB ZC -etc ZZ
AAA -AAB - AAAC
```

I think you can get the idea.
I literally have no idea where to start with this so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you'll need some arrays of the letters at the very least. And some loops. It's not clear how many levels high you want this staircase, so maybe one of those loops is a `while` with a condition controlled by something a user can cancel. The name of the game here on Stack Overflow is research; we kind of expect people to quite a bit of it before asking, and to show that research in the question.

Comment: This pattern looks kinda familliar: `1, 2, 3 ... 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ... 19, 20, 21 ... 98, 99, 100, 101, 102 ...` or in hex `0x0, 0x1, 0x2 ... 0xE, 0xF, 0x10, 0x11 ... 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F, ... 0xFD, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0x100, 0x101 ... 0x10F ... 0xFFE, 0xFFF, 0x1000` do you see it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look a reduced version of this problem:  well only use the letters
A, B, and C, not the whole alphabeth.

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

for the first "level" we don't even need a loop.
with the method "join", we can turn the array into a string:

```
console.log( letters.join(" - ") );
```

for the second level we need one loop to set the
letter, and then join to the second letter.

```
for(first_letter of letters) {
     string = letters.map(second_letter => first_letter + second_letter ).join(" - ")
     console.log(string);
}
```

for higher levels I first thought of recursion, but we can just
build on the results of the last level. to get from an array containing
staircase level i to level i+1 we build the new array by add A to the front of the whole staircase, then B, and so on...

```js
let output = document.querySelector('main');

let letters = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let staircase = letters.slice(); // clone the array

console.log(`Staircase level 1`);
console.log( staircase.join(" - "));


for (let level = 2; level < 5; level++) {
  let new_staircase = [];
  for (let firstletter of letters) {
    new_staircase.push(...staircase.map(string => firstletter + string));
  }
  staircase = new_staircase;
  console.log(`Staircase level ${level}`);
  console.log( staircase.join(" - "));
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'd need recursion necessarily. Couldn't the same thing be done simply by having a loop that executes x number of times inside another loop that takes any number and runs it in increments of 26? That sounds confusing but hopefully it makes sense. I think it can be done without recursion.